# Joystick для игры "Змейка 3D" на Unity3D не работает корректно

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Я достаточно долго создаю игру Змейка 3D. Сейчас я решил делать управление для телефона, для этого я импортировал "Joystick pack" из Asset store. Я добавил в код управления змеёй сам джойстик, но код отказывается работать:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SnakeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 6;
    public float RotationSpeed = 300;

    public float z_ofset = -0.01f;
    public GameObject tailPrefab;
    public List<GameObject> tailObject = new List<GameObject>();
    public Text onScreen;
    public int score;
    public Joystick joystick;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        tailObject.Add(gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        onScreen.text = "Score = " + score;
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Input.Joystick(joystick.Horizontal))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.Joystick(joystick.Horizontal))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
    public void AddTail()
    {
        Vector3 newtailPosition = tailObject[tailObject.Count - 1].transform.position;
        newtailPosition.z += z_ofset;
        tailObject.Add(GameObject.Instantiate(tailPrefab, newtailPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject);


    }
    public void ScoreAll(){
        score = score + 1;
    }
}
```

При компиляции программы у меня в Unity появляется ошибка:

```
error CS0117: 'input' does not contain a definition for 'Joystick'
```

Comment: Подсказка: `"Score = " + score`, если вам важна производительность интерфейса, не следует перерисовывать постоянно ту часть текста, которая `Score =`, она никогда не меняется. Разбейте на 2 `Text` контрола, в первый поместите тот текст, который не меняется, во второй уже то что нужно менять. Наверняка у вас еще есть похожие реализации, проверьте код. Хотя я не очень хорошо знаю Unity, может оно и всё равно, но хуже точно не будет.

Comment: `код отказывается работать` - как вы это поняли?

Comment: Два одинаковых условия "joystick.Horizontal" - это нормально? О_о

Comment: @aepot я это понял, потому что мне выдаёт ошибку error CS0117: 'input' does not contain a definition for 'Joystick'

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Явно это не нормально, но я не совсем уверен, как это можно прописать...

Comment: @aepot Я внёс информацию

Comment: @aepot, не влияет на производительность, при любом изменении, завово отрисовывается весь `Canvas`. Проблема скорее в том что событийное происходит в `Update`.

Comment: Этот пак не юзал. Если не ошибаюсь, просто `joystick.Horizontal`, он не часть `input`.

Comment: @Yaroslav понял, спасибо. Я скорее сагрился на конкатенацию строк :)

Comment: @Yaroslav Да, по видимому ```joystick.Horizontal``` не является частью ```input```, но как это решить я не знаю...

Comment: Что решить?......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня получилось решить проблему с кодом, решение было достаточно близко:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SnakeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 6;
    public float RotationSpeed = 300;

    public float z_ofset = -0.01f;
    public GameObject tailPrefab;
    public List<GameObject> tailObject = new List<GameObject>();
    public Text onScreen;
    public int score;
    public Joystick joystick;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        tailObject.Add(gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        onScreen.text = "Score = " + score;
        transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Speed * Time.deltaTime);
        Vector3 direction1 = Vector3.up * joystick.Horizontal;
        transform.Rotate(direction1 * RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
    public void AddTail()
    {
        Vector3 newtailPosition = tailObject[tailObject.Count - 1].transform.position;
        newtailPosition.z += z_ofset;
        tailObject.Add(GameObject.Instantiate(tailPrefab, newtailPosition, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject);


    }
    public void ScoreAll(){
        score = score + 1;
    }
}
```